# Replacing text with jQuery only in active/focussed input-Element

Tags: html, jquery

I have a page where I have around 10 `input`-Elements. Some of them I gave the class `.no-whitespace-allowed`. Now I have a jQuery script running in the background with the purpose to avoid whitespaces in the very `input`-Elements:

```
$(function() {
    var elements = $(".no_whitespace_allowed");
    var func = function() {
        if (elements.is(':focus')) elements.val(elements.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
        else elements.val(elements.val());
    }
    elements.keyup(func).blur(func);
  });
```

However, it replaces the text in every input field with the result that I have the same text in all inputs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  $(".no_whitespace_allowed").keyup(function(){
 $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '') );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input class="no_whitespace_allowed" type="text">
```

Something like this ?